# How can maintain a SqlConnection open always

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, sqlconnection

How can maintain a SqlConnection (or using another component) open (connected) always during the execution of my .Net app?

I need this because my app needs to detect using this commnad

```
 exec sp_who2
```

how many instances of my app are connected to mydatabase, to restrict the access (license control).

example

A) my app executed from **location1**

1. check the number of my apps connected to the sql server using `exec sp_who2`
2. if the number of **my applications < MaxLicencesConnected** then start my app and open a sqlconnection

B) my app executed from **location2**

1. check the number of my apps connected to the sql server using `exec sp_who2`
2. if the number of **my applications >= MaxLicencesConnected** then close my application

sorry for my english.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection pooling keeps the connection alive:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't it be easier to simply have a table where you add a record when the program starts and remove it when the program exits? Keeping a connection to SQL Server open all the time is quite expensive.

Technically, someone could come along a delete the record and start up a new instance, but obviously if they do that then the first instance is going to stop working (assuming it checks for the presense of it's own record every now and then).

Answer (score 1):

Use **connection pooling**. Set **Max Pool Size** and **Min Pool Size** and **Pooling** in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Myabe you can set a connection object, open it and store in a global (static) variable. I beleive, you would also have to set the timeout of the connection, otherwise it will be closed automaticaly if let idle.

Franly speaking, I dont think keeping a connection open is a good idea, as they are expensive.